# Image is 90 degree left rotated after encoding to Base64 Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, base64, flutter-image-picker

I am using the chooseImage function to pick an image and sending the avatar value to the server. The problem is sometimes some image is changed its original orientation. Most of time it rotate to left 90 degree. Is there any problem in my code? How can I solve this ?

I am using this package to pick image:

> **image_picker: ^1.0.4**

```
final imageFile = useState<File?>(null);
final avatar = useState('');

Future<void> chooseImage(type) async {
  XFile? image;
  if (type == "camera") {
    image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  } else {
    image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  }
  if (image != null) {
    imageFile.value = File(image.path);
    final bytes = imageFile.value!.readAsBytesSync();
    avatar.value = 
      Uri.dataFromBytes(bytes, mimeType: "appication/png").toString()
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a front camera for your images? if so it rotates the image by default

Comment: No, I am picking the image from the gallery, and for the camera, I'm using rear camera. Images that rotated their original orientation were all picked from the gallery.

Comment: I have a feeling you are facing an issue i saw one of my friend face, can you try this out and if it works i can add it as an answer https://genuinecoder.com/flutter-camera-image-orientation-rotation-issue-fix/#:~:text=Flutter%20image_picker%20has%20a%20bug,manually%20as%20the%20metadata%20suggests.